# LibYUI-ncurses (YaST2) on Ubuntu 16.04 build problems

Tags: user-interface, ubuntu, cmake, ncurses, tui

all!

Im trying to build latest git version libyui on ununtu 16.04.2 but with no luck... So, could somebody help me build ncurses version?

This is  libyui-ncurses/VERSION.cmake

```
SET( VERSION_MAJOR "2" )
SET( VERSION_MINOR "47" )
SET( VERSION_PATCH "6" )
SET( VERSION "${VERSION_MAJOR}.${VERSION_MINOR}.${VERSION_PATCH}${GIT_SHA1_VERSION}" )

##### This is need for the libyui core, ONLY.
##### These will be overridden from exports in LibyuiConfig.cmake
SET( SONAME_MAJOR "5" )
SET( SONAME_MINOR "0" )
SET( SONAME_PATCH "0" )
SET( SONAME "${SONAME_MAJOR}.${SONAME_MINOR}.${SONAME_PATCH}" )
```

and here is the problem with ncurses6...

```
$ cmake ..
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done

CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:148 (message):
Could NOT find Curses6 (missing: CURSES6_LIBRARIES)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
/usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:388 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
cmake/Modules/FindCurses6.cmake:25 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
/usr/share/libyui/buildtools/LibyuiCommon.cmake:231 (FIND_PACKAGE)
CMakeLists.txt:46 (FIND_LIB_DEPENDENCIES)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/stalker/projects/libyui-ncurses/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Thanks for advance!
Alex

Comment: Error message means that it fails to find Curses6 libraries. By looking into  `FindCurse6.cmake` [source](https://github.com/libyui/libyui-ncurses/blob/master/cmake/Modules/FindCurses6.cmake), you may find names of these libraries: `ncursesw`, `panelw` and `tinfo` (the last one is optional).

Answer (score 0):

The [cmake module](https://github.com/libyui/libyui-ncurses/blob/master/cmake/Modules/FindCurses6.cmake) was committed 3 years ago, and appears to be looking for ncurses under "ncurses6".  Likely that was based on someone's *private build* since ncurses6 was released just over a year ago.  Until that point, there were options to build ABI=6, but no third-party packages.